# Animals containing the word "monster"?

Tags: single-word-requests, kinship-terms

My children have become most concerned with monsters, especially since discovering *Scooby Doo.* Other than Gila monsters, are there other animals containing the word **monster**?

Note: I have done typical web searches and online taxonomy resources. I have also seen every episode of *Wild Kraats* at least twice.

Comment: Is there not a searchable list of animals that you can use? Anyway, is this really about English Language?

Comment: I don't know. If I start losing points than I suppose not.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not appear to be about English language and usage within the scope defined in the help center. It is a request for a list, and should be addressed by personal searches on Google and in collocation dictionaries.

Comment: I don't know about others with the word "monster" in their name, but National Geographic Kids highlights eight animals with spooky names here: <http://kids.nationalgeographic.com/explore/awesome-8-hub/animals-spooky-names/>.

Comment: lockness monster?

Comment: Taking 'animal' figuratively, and given that children are involved, you might be interested in the "**baby monster** *n.* the second-largest known sporadic finite simple group, discovered at the same time as the monster group." Aside from that totally off-answer gem, the closest thing on the order of a 'Gila monster' revealed by a search in *OED Online* appears to be a 'water monster' (one-time name of a flying fish); that and all others are creatures of legend, fable, science fiction, figurative language, etc., unlike the Gila monster.

Comment: Let's not forget **Cookie Monster**.

Comment: There also seems to be the [Tully monster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tullimonstrum), (See also this [article](http://www.theatlantic.com/science/archive/2016/03/solving-the-mystery-of-the-tully-monster/473823/)) but it's extinct and only known by its fossils.